# XCode 4.2 project migrating to XCode 4.2.1

Tags: xcode, ios5, xcode4.2, osx-lion, upgrade

Apologies if this is not considered enough of a programming question for SO (it is development related in a round about way).

I've got an iMac at 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard). I've been working on an iOS 5 project using storyboards, which would not work on our test iPhone (it was at version 4.3.5). I updated the iPhone to iOS 5.0.1 in hopes that this would fix the issue.

Plug in the phone, can't select it from XCode 4.2, because it only support iOS 5.0 and below. So now I must upgrade to XCode 4.2.1, which requires updating the iMac to 10.7 (Lion). After shaking my fist and cursing at Apple, I've talked my manager into letting me do all of the necessary upgrades. However, I'd like to make sure of a couple things before I go through with this:

1. Will my XCode 4.2 project still open in XCode 4.2.1 (or is there a safe way to convert it). I'd like to avoid rewriting the application.
2. I've saved my XCode project folder on a usb key to ensure I don't lose the application. Does this also save the git repo (where is the git repo stored by default? I'd like to keep the history if possible)?
3. What do I need to do as far as developer and distribution keys and certificates? Do I need to export them and reimport them after the upgrade to 10.7?
4. Is there anything else that I need to back up before doing this upgrade (related to my iPhone application and anything else related to development/distribution)?

TIA

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes. No need to convert.
2. Git repro is stored within the project's top level directory. You are safe to transport it via your USB flash drive and not lose the repo.
3. It has been awhile since I upgraded to 10.7, but I do not recall having to regenerate my certificates.
4. Just be sure to do a backup of your data "just in case", but I was able to upgrade without any issues. However, I have read about many failed attempts, so it is best to error on the side of caution.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. I'll try it out (scheduled upgrade is later this week) and we'll see how it goes. +1 for now and a pending marked as correct answer after I confirm the upgrade.

Comment: We ended up using our iPad (was at version 5.0), which could emulate the iPhone. That was enough to get the app out the door so-to-speak. The Mac has been upgraded, but I haven't gotten it back yet (won't until we make upgrades to the application... it was just a side project since we don't have a regular iPhone developer, so it may be a while).